# WSGI script cannot be loaded

Tags: python, wsgi

I'm having trouble getting my python app to be accessible via Apache, however it runs fine on my local machine and on the server if loaded directly from `sudo python __init__.py`

My apache error.log file shows the following --

Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module

Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'

I've followed the [tutorial here](http://leonwang.me/post/deploy-flask) to setup the server initially but it hasn't worked for me. According to the Apache Log wsgi is being complied with python 3.5.2 which is perfect, however I'm still getting the errors seen below. Any suggestions? I've spent about 2 hours googling this and haven't found a good answer yet.

**EDIT**
Here is the traceback following the above errors:

[Tue Jul 04 01:39:04.048803 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 2814:tid 140542235064064] [client 209.159.217.240:50426] mod_wsgi (pid=2814): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://legendaryroller.com/

[Tue Jul 04 01:39:04.048856 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 2814:tid 140542235064064] [client 209.159.217.240:50426] mod_wsgi (pid=2814): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'., referer: http://legendaryroller.com/

[Tue Jul 04 01:39:04.048939 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 2814:tid 140542235064064] [client 209.159.217.240:50426] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://legendaryroller.com/

[Tue Jul 04 01:39:04.048961 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 2814:tid 140542235064064] [client 209.159.217.240:50426]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in , referer: http://legendaryroller.com/

[Tue Jul 04 01:39:04.048965 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 2814:tid 140542235064064] [client 209.159.217.240:50426]     from FlaskApp import app as application, referer: http://legendaryroller.com/

Edit Two:

Here is the WSGI file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'your secret key'
```

Here is the FlaskApp.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName legendaryroller.com
        ServerAlias 34.229.198.127 
            ServerAdmin admin@email.com
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: After that message in the Apache error log there should be other messages which indicate what the issue is. Include those messages in your question.

Comment: Could you include ```flaskapp.wsgi``` and ```FlaskApp.conf```?, are you using virtualenv?

Comment: That is not the full traceback, nor does it contain the name of the exception raised, nor the description with it. Provide all the stack frames, plus details of the exception.

Comment: I am using virtualenv, I provided the wsgi file, and copied all the text out of the apache error log file and provided the flaskapp.conf

Comment: Just a guess. Did you check the permission? Which user is running the apache server? Does it have access to the code? Also if you are using virtualenv, are you sure the apache is also using it?

Comment: Even after you update, that traceback is still missing the name of the exception raised and description that one would expect to see in the logs.

Comment: Not related but ``ServerAlias`` shouldn't be set to an IP address. That should be removed as no point having it.

Comment: That's all I've got. I copied the entire file.

Comment: You also must have a strange global configuration for Apache which already allows access under ``/var/www`` as that first ``Directory`` block should use ``/var/www/FlaskApp`` and not ``/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp``. The error if that were failing as expect would be very different though as would be from Apache block it and not mod_wsgi.

Comment: BTW, you also should use daemon mode of mod_wsgi and not embedded mode. Look at examples of daemon mode and how to set up a Python virtual environment properly in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton thanks for all your pointers! I'll do some more reading and see what happens. Maybe I'll even just try rebuilding the server to see if I made mistake and just fat fingered something in.

Comment: I figured it out! I had to do the following... 
`import sys
sys.path.append("/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp")` because local imports were failing. Thanks for all the help guys!